# Какими инструментами из ассемблера можно получить C код?

Tags: c, ассемблер, обратная-разработка, декомпиляция

Какими инструментами из ассемблера можно получить C код?

Comment: Мозгами, прежде всего.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю с поисками декомпилятора будут проблемы. Да вот вопрос: зачем это вообще надо? Есть же замечательный дизассемблер [IDA](http://www.idapro.ru/) - лучше тулзины для разборок с бинарниками не встречал.

Comment: Причем именно IDA и именно с планином Hex-Rays

Answer (score 2):

Hex-Rays. наверное пока лучший продукт.